# Binary operations between two 0-dim ndarrays don't preserve type

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

[The docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.ndarray.html#arithmetic-matrix-multiplication-and-comparison-operations) about `ndarray` state the following:

> Arithmetic and comparison operations on ndarrays are defined as element-wise operations, and generally yield ndarray objects as results.

This makes sense as it would be very surprising if `type(x) == type(y)` but `type(x {op} y) != type(x)` (where `{op}` stands for an arbitrary binary operator).

However, `np.ndarray` seems to behave that way if `ndim == 0` for both operands:

```py
>>> x = np.array(1.)
>>> f'{x = }, {x.ndim = }'
'x = array(1.), x.ndim = 0'
>>> f'{x+x = }, {type(x+x) = }'
"x+x = 2.0, type(x+x) = <class 'numpy.float64'>"
```

This is inconvenient because my code assumes that binary operations *do* preserve the type (which is reasonable). Also, static type checking won't capture that:

```py
from typing import TypeVar
import numpy as np

T = TypeVar('T', bound=np.ndarray)

def add(x: T, y: T) -> T:
    return x + y

a = np.array(1.)
assert isinstance(add(a, a), np.ndarray)
```

According to mypy this snippet contains no issues but the assertion fails when run.

Is there a way to configure Numpy such that it will preserve the `ndarray` type even for 0-dim arrays?

Comment: `np.add(x, y, out=np.empty_like(x))` preserves the output.

Comment: @MYousefi So does `np.array(x + y)` and `(np.atleast_1d(x) + y).squeeze()` but all of this are very complicated ways of spelling `x + y` and, even more important, they require explicit knowledge of the type, so I can't use duck typing anymore. In my above `add` function, I would specifically have to check whether the inputs are `ndarray`, then apply the workaround. Also it means whenever I have a binary operation involving Numpy arrays, I can't just write `x {op} y` but I need to apply a workaround which hurts readability *a lot*.

Comment: I see. That I don't know of a way around. None of the configurations that I know of in python do something like this. Since `ufunc` in numpy is done on the C backend I'm not very familiar with it.

Comment: I found [this](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/4563), [this](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/5819) and [this](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/13105) tnreads on github.com discussing this issue. The discussion seems to suggest this is by design. Unfortunately, there's no proper solution recommended in the discussions.

Comment: I don't think you'll find a good solution.  Numpy just blurs the distinction between 0-d arrays and scalars.